# google sheets - How to combine multiple mini-tables into one table

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

**Q: How do I get all the data from each of the mini tables into one list?**

I have a staff rota on a spreadsheet, 35 "mini-tables" arranged in 5(weeks) rows of 7(days). I'm not allowed to change how the tables look. The columns are the same in each one, but the rows and data are variable.  I gave them all a named range, basically numbered them from "one" to "thirtyfive".

In another tab I want to be able to combine the data from all of them into one list, ignoring blank rows, so I can query it.  Ultimately I want a tab for each item of a list that is used for data validation in one of the cols of each table, but I would be okay with just filtering a sorted list of all the data.  Hope that makes sense ... here is a link to the sheet.  I have added a little dummy data, and you can see what I was trying and failing to do in the third tab

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GxTWWB2cEAXh-DG8pHY7sOMPn3-a1CIkvkxzxRq4xAI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Just a suggestion, but it might make it easier to work with your 35 tables as named ranges if you called them something like T01, T02, T03,..., T35, instead of the longer names you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your sample data quite confusing to work with, but I think I have an answer for you.  Try the following formula, in A1 of Sheet6 of your sample sheet.  Does it give you the merged list of data, as you want it?

```
=SORT( 
  QUERY({one;two;three;four;five;six;seven;eight;nine;ten;eleven;twelve;thirteen;fourteen;
         fifteen;sixteen;seventeen;eighteen;nineteen;twenty;twentyone;twentytwo;twentythree;
         twentyfour;twentyfive;twentysix;twentyseven;twentyeight;twentynine;thirty;thirtyone;
         thirtytwo;thirtythree;thirtyfour;thirtyfive},       
    "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7 where Col8  CONTAINS '"&K1&"'", 1) , 1, TRUE)
```

[image]